# Android AIML BOT?

Tags: android, c++, integration, aiml

I have a few Questions related to AIML integration in the Android OS. I know not much of Java but I do know a lot about AIML. I made the AIML files and now what I want to do is to make one app which can load the files and run them in a GUI. Please tell me a way to do this. If AIML is not possible, is there a C++ way to do it? Please reply fast. I know C++, C and AIML. Not much JAVA or other programming Languages. I am not interested in hosting a web based application as I don't  have a site and can't get one.

FYI- AIML stands for 'Artificial Intelligence Markup Language'.

natarajadithyan.

Comment: Unless you take the time to explain what "load the files and run them in a GUI" mean to you, you will have just about as much luck asking your questions to your favorite AIML bot.

Comment: What I mean is just to make a GUI which would access the AIML files and give outputs. Basically an input output GUI. Say u type hello in the text box, it should check the .aiml files and say hello or hey or hi or whatever it is coded to reply.

Answer (score 2):

The chatterbots use a complicated algorithm. Simply, the chatterbot executable searches for categories with the underscore wildcard. Next, categories with no wildcard are searched. Last, the star wildcards are checked. When the pattern matches the input, then the AIML interpreter handles the code in the template tags. You may want to look at the source code for this chatterbot to get an idea about how they work.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/qaiml/

Answer (score 2):

Try program-ab.

It's written in java and very easy to integrate in an android app.

I don't know if there is any c/c++ chatbots. If it's available then you can try integrating them using Android Native development kit(called NDK).

NDK is used to write android apps in c++. I personally wont be able to help you with NDK.

But I have integrated program-ab into android app using java. Its pretty simple.